rewrite in Nginx-Ingress virtualServer hostname to different hostname
I have a nginx configuration as
server {
    rewrite ^/my-old-page$ /my-new-page/? permanent;
}

Now we are migrating to K8s and we want to replicate the nginx configuration with nginx-ingress virtualServer.
Using:
apiVersion: k8s.nginx.org/v1
kind: VirtualServer

From the documentation, I don't find a direct alternate to do the same.
Do we have a way to redirect the host based URL to a different host
like service1.example.com/xyz to service2.example.com/abc

As per this blog by matthew, try using Action.redirect you can  redirect the client to a new URL.

have you tried creating an ingress rule with rewrite annotation?

If answer is a question then better include it as comments.
